# Why cannot the value be fed into the `placeholder_with_default' in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I just used TensorFlow (version 1.8.0) to train a model. Here, I used `tf.placeholder_with_default` to initialize a placeholder:

`t_iteration = tf.placeholder_with_default(-1, [], name='t_iteration')` (so the default value of `t_iteration` is -1 if there is no value fed into the placeholder. After that, I used `sess.run(t_iteration, feed_dict={t_iteration: 2})` to try to feed a value of 2 into this placeholder.

However, it is very strange that when I used `B = t_iteration.eval(session=sess)` to convert the tensor to an array and check the value that I have fed, the B always equals to -1 not 2. I don't know the reason about this? Seems the `sess.run(t_iteration, feed_dict={t_iteration: 2})` didn't work.

Could you help me with this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: A placeholder is stateless. When you run sess.run(), t_iteration is set to 2 on for that session execution. After that when you use .eval() it has no knowledge of what you have done before.

Comment: @thushv89 Hi, many thanks for your help. Is there other way to get the updated value in placeholder using .eval()?